# DOM appendChild to insert images

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this code that creates links.

```
   /* Create a link to activate the tab */
    DOM_a = document.createElement("a");
    DOM_a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t.headingText));
    DOM_a.href = "javascript:void(null);";
    DOM_a.title = t.headingText;
    DOM_a.onclick = this.navClick;
```

I need to add an image to the link, but when I try to add the image code:

```
<img src="typo3conf/ext/ori_proyectos/res/images/interes.png">
```

I get:

```
Link<img src="typo3conf/ext/ori_proyectos/res/images/interes.png">
```

And not:
`Link[*_*]`

Where `[*_*]` is the image.

The source code display this:

```
&lt;img src="typo3conf/ext/ori_proyectos/res/images/interes.png"&gt;
```

I don't know how to write it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should create the image using own DOM methods too:

**Something like this:**

```
var DOM_img = document.createElement("img");
DOM_img.src = "typo3conf/ext/ori_proyectos/res/images/interes.png";

DOM_a.appendChild(DOM_img);
```

A working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/snake/UPQqN/).

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! In 10 minutes I will choose your answer. Do you now why < changed to &lt;?

Comment: @Memochipan You created a text node from the source. A text node does not contain any HTML elements, hence `<` etc is replaced by HTML entities (`&lt;`, etc).