# Is there any way to insert image using "prompt()" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-deployment, prompt

I want to insert an image using `prompt()` in **JavaScript**

Here is the thing I tried :

`var name = prompt("Enter your name");` [Typeof string or number]

**What I want is:**

`var profile_img = prompt("Choose Your Picture");` [Typeof img]

Comment: Almost certainly not. But ascii art would be possible... if it is an acceptable substitute for your use case

Comment: I would write an implementation of prompts yourself, or use a library -- SweetAlert comes to mind. https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: Just don't use any of the `prompt`, `alert` etc. methods. You'll save you a lot of troubles. These are from ages we don't want to remember. Go with a proper interface that won't block your UI and that you will be able to control 100%.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. A [`window.prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) call only accepts text input.

Depending on your use case, the user could enter the public URL to an image (any supported protocol, even the pseude-scheme `data:`) and your script could then fetch the image from the given URL. Another possibility mentioned by [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4385889/andrew) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67716579/is-there-any-way-to-insert-image-using-prompt-in-javascript/67716594#comment119692795_67716579): have users input an encoded version of the image (base64, hexdump, …) and then parse it yourself to get back the binary image data.

To then insert the image into your DOM, see other questions and answers on Stackoverflow, such as [DOM appendChild to insert images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7932759/112968):

```
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = 'path/to/image';

parent_element.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Is there any way to insert img anything in javaScript?

Comment: @Towker_joy what do you mean? `let img = new Image(); element.appendChild(img);`?

Comment: can you show some examples?
I want to make a project like this: anyone visits my site but this site fully blank. user can input his name, about, img anything than Press Enter. Than javascript process all data and img and make a website/page with his data

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use `<input type="file" ..` and trigger it with the js

Assuming you have jQuery, but the principle should work regardless

```
<input id="myInput" type="file" style="visibility:hidden" />
<input type="button" value="Show Dialog" onclick="$('#myInput').click();" />
```

Then look at [this answer how to display the image without uploading it to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138244/how-to-display-selected-image-without-sending-data-to-server/17138290)